# Codeigniter reload page with id in url

Tags: php, codeigniter

On this site that I’m coding I have a page that is accessible through the following urls:

http://site.com/campaigns/view/

which displays a default view of all campaigns and lets say

http://site.com/campaigns/view/8

which displays details for campaign 8

On this page I have a form from which you can add subscribers to the specific campaign.
My controller logic goes something like this:

```
$campaign_id = $this -> uri -> segment(3);
$this -> campaign_model -> get_campaign_details(3);

// Form was submitted
if ($this -> input -> post()) {
    //code to check inputs and save subscriber
} else {
    // Display page with campaign details
}
```

Now my problem is, in the else branch, how would I go about displaying the page with the campaign details. I’ve tried
`redirect("campaigns/view/8")` 
which creates a redirect loop and also

```
$this -> load -> view("campaigns/view/".$campaign_id)
```

which of course tries to load a view 8.php that doesn’t exist.
So how would I go about implementing the functionality for something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Jim

EDIT:

If there isn't a post submit what I would like to see is the details, which includes among others the list of subscribers, for campaign number 8, 9 etc.

If there is a post submit I would like to see the details page again which of course this time would include the newly added subscriber.

Submit again -> add subscriber -> details view again and so on.

Comment: Ahhhhh! I never realized how difficult code is to read with spaces around the `->`!

Comment: @Hailwood Sorry about that, I write like that because me editor highlights the -> only if I have spaces around it!

Comment: 'tis ok, I was just playing, it doesn't really matter, a code style is the developers choice!

Answer (score 0):

you need to specific what you'd like to output in case of campaign 8 when not after a post submit..
Of course redirection just comes back to the same page.

What behavior would you like to see happen?

Comment: If there isn't a post submit what I would like to see is the details, which includes among others the list of subscribers, for campaign number 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
// If no `campaign_id` in the url, set campaign id to 0
$campaign_id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);

$this->load->model('campaign_model');

// Form was submitted
if ($this->input->post()) {
    //code to check inputs and save subscriber
}

if ($campaign_id > 0) {
    $data['campaign_details'] = $this->campaign_model->get_campaign_details($campaign_id);
    // Display page with campaign details
    $this->load->view('campaign/details', $data);
}
else {
    $data['campaign_list'] = $this->campaign_model->get_campaign_list();
    // Display list of campaigns
    $this->load->view('campaign/list', $data);
}
```

Comment: I still don't think this solves my original problem. I want to add a subscriber and then loop back to the details page for the campaign and then add another subscriber and so on.

Comment: If you are in `campaign details/view/8`, you can display/send a form with `action="campaign/details/8"`. So the campaign id is known, you catch the POST variables and add the subscriber to that #8 campaign before deciding what view to display, which will be `campaign/details/8` with the newly added subscriber.